# Regex to select last word from path

Tags: regex

I have some strings like the following:

```
C:/DB/UCMerced_LandUse/UCMerced_LandUse/Unfoldered_Images/airplane00.tif
```

I would like to keep only `'airplane'`. For that, I've come up with the following regexes:

`[^/]+$` - which would select `'airplane00.tif'`

`^\D*`   - which removes the last part (i.e. `'C:/DB/UCMerced_LandUse/UCMerced_LandUse/Unfoldered_Images/airplane'`)

How can I combine these two in order to get only `'airplane'`? Or perhaps there is a better approach...

Thank you.

Comment: do you have to do it with regex? You can easily achieve this by splitting string and replacing digits. Which language you are using?

Comment: @shakhawat it is Python, but I need a regex as a string for a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and grab captured group #1

```
([^/\d]+)[^/]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIF84V/2/)

`[^/\d]+` matches 1 or more of any character that is not `\d` and `/`.

**Alternatively**, you can also use this regex with lookbehind and lookahead assertions:

```
(?<=/)[^/\d]+(?=[^/]*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `([^\/]+)\.\D+$` and match the first capturing group.

It is probably better though to use some built-in functionality of your programming language to get the filename from the path. Also splitting the string would be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[^\]([a-zA-Z]+)[^\].*$
```

Then you just need to get the first group.

In python, all you need to do is add `.group(1)` to the end of your line.

[check out this article about capturing groups](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html?wlr=1)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could match until the last occurrence of `/`, then capture any char except a forward slash or digit in a group `([^/\d]+)\d*` and match any potentially following digits.

Then match a dot and any char except a forward slash.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
/([^/\d]+)\d*\.[^/]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MUCofp/1)